# How to count the number of applications running in background in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to get the number of applications currently running in the background using the following code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int numberOfApps =  runningAppProcessInfo.size();
```

But even though more than 1 application is running in the background the code is returning 1.

Comment: Yeah, but you need a scary permission for your app in order to do it (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS). Edit: this is scary because it is a permission that most apps shouldn't need, and from a user standpoint makes your app considerably less trustworthy unless you have a very obvious reason for needing it.

The method to achieve what you are after is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

Comment: but this method is deprecated  for lollipop.is there any other solution?